# Various errors in a header file regarding a single type

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm getting a number of errors in my header file that i can't seem to solve. They all seem to be in the lines that use the `class Tutor` type.

Here's my code:

```js
#pragma once
#include "Pupil.h"
#include "Tutor.h"
class Class
{
 char name;
 int num;
 Pupil** pupils;
 int pupil_amount;
 Tutor* tutor;
public:
 Class();
 Class(char, int);
 ~Class();
 bool Add_Pupil(Pupil* p);
 Pupil* Get_Pupil(int ind);
 int Get_Amount()const { return pupil_amount; }//get the amount of pupils
 int Get_Num()const { return num; }//get the name of the class
 Tutor* Get_Tutor()const { return tutor; } //return a pointer to the tutor
 void Add_Tutor(Tutor* t) { tutor = t; }//set a tutor recieved as a pointer
 char Get_Name()const { return name; }

};
```

These are the errors:

[image]

I solved it by declaring the class "Tutor" as a friend but then my professor told me not to use friend declarations.
I tried moving the function to the .cpp file with no luck.

Is there any way i can solve this without using friend?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because compiler doesn't have declaration of 'Tutor' class when compiling your 'Class'. Check that 'Tutor.h' really contains declaration of the Tutor class.

Comment: I just added a declaration and it worked. So first of all thank you!

Is it possible that it was not declared because tutor inherits from another class?

Comment: It doesn't depend whether it's inherited or not. The class should be declared before first use, in the same header file or included.